# Mass transport in continuum mechanics fashion

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, continuum-mechanics

I'm looking for a book/paper/website/whatever that introduces mass transport from a continuum mechanical perspective, as in: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00419-017-1287-0 , section 2.2 and 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in case someone else is searching for the same. I found those books/manuscripts useful:

[Mixture Theory Manuscript, Prague University](http://geo.mff.cuni.cz/~soucek/vyuka/materials/theory-of-mixtures/theory_of_mixtures-lecture-notes.pdf)

[Non-equilibrium Thermodynamics, Gyarmati](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783642510694)

[Non-equilibrium Thermodynamics, de Groot, Mazur](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486647412)

[Rational Thermodynamics, Truesdell](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9781461297376)